# java cachedThreadPool kill submitted threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to do some multi-threading work, and I use `ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool()` and submit some job retrieved from a queue.

```
public class ContentParser {
    public static ExecutorService cachedThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    // ...

    public static void queueExecutor(Content content)  {
        String url = "";
        while ((url = queue.poll()) != null){
            LOG.info("Picked url " + url);
            cachedThreadPool.submit(new ParserCallable(content, url));
        }
    }

    // ...

private static class ParserCallable implements Runnable {
    private Content content;
    private String url;
    private ParserCallable(Content content, String url) {
        this.url = url;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        new FontParser().fontSearcher(content, url);
    }
}
```

So each thread creates a new instance of `FontParser` and inside it I do some job.

I call my `ContentParser.queueExecutor` from another class, so after all jobs are submitted I do:

```
ContentParser.cachedThreadPool.shutdown();
ContentParser.cachedThreadPool.awaitTermination(5l, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

But it just kills my threads even if the work isn't finished and doesn't wait.

Maybe it's because I create a new instance `new FontParser().fontSearcher(content, url);` in every thread?

Comment: Are you sure that all your threads are killed? "awaitTermination" will also return if threads are completed and shutdown of pool is done ...

Comment: sorry, I think maybe there was some Exception throwed but I didnt noticed. I need to check.

Comment: If you do not have exception, other possible reason would be : insufficient timeout in awaitTermination method. Please make sure that timeout duration is long enough for already submitted tasks to complete with-in that period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I call my ContentParser.queueExecutor from another class, so after all jobs are submitted I do:

It sounds like you are saying that someone is calling `cachedThreadPool.shutdown()` but jobs are still being submitted to the pool.  That should never happen.  `shutdown()` should be called only after you `poll()` loop completes.

I'd recommend doing something like the following in your `queueExecutor(...)` method:

```
while ((url = queue.poll()) != null){
    LOG.info("Picked url " + url);
    cachedThreadPool.submit(new ParserCallable(content, url));
}
// shutdown _after_ all jobs have been submitted
cachedThreadPool.shutdown();
```

Also, in general, it is a bad practice to make fields public -- especially in this case your `cachedThreadPool` field.  You can't control how (or in this case when) external classes call critical methods on your pool.  I'd make it private then have an await method on your `ContentParser` class:

```
private static ExecutorService cachedThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
...
public static void awaitPoolTermination(/* maybe timeout args here */) {
    cachedThreadPool.awaitTermination(5l, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

This better controls your thread-pool and doesn't allow the shutdown at the improper place.  So then the caller of the `ContentParser` methods would first call `contentParser.queueExecutor(...)` and then call `contentParser.awaitPoolTermination(...)`.